# Multiple contacts to single account

Tags: apex

I am working with  custom webservice how can i asign multiple contacts to single account, in custom webservice. Can any one give some sample code?

MY code is

```
        ct;
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return res;
     }   

          return res;
  }

}
```

Comment: Sathy please try to only use related tags, if your question is purely on how to connect contacts to accounts in apex, the question is not about webservices or soap.

Answer (score 3):

Account and Contact are standard salesforce objects. Account is a parent object of the contacts so if creating a new contact you need to set account id (`AccountId` field):

```
// Reading account from the database (it is not realy necessary to do this 
// if you have already account id)
Account acc = [Select Id, Name From Account Where LastName = 'Jones' Limit 1];

//Creating a list of the future contacts to be able to insert many contacts at one time
List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();

// Creating two contact objects and setting mandatory fields
Contact contact1 = new Contact(LastName = 'LastName1',
                               AccountId = acc.id);
Contact contact2 = new Contact(LastName = 'LastName2',
                               AccountId = acc.id);

// Adding contacts to the list
contacts.add(contact1);
contacts.add(contact2);

// Inserting new contacts
upsert contacts;
```

For better undestanding take a look at the salesofrce documantation about [standard object `Contact`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

Comment: @Masto7 i am using like this but i am getting an error at

Comment: @Sathya What error?

Comment: @Mastor Variable does not exist: contacts at line for bold lines it getting an error

Comment: @mastor i write a comments in myweservice for error occuring point.once check it.

Comment: @Sathya Yes this is right. If you look at you code you will see that the global class `RequestClass` has no variable `contacts`, only `accounts`. So you referencing a wrong class.

Comment: @Mastor May i know how can i modify my code based upon that.

Comment: @Sathya You may need to reference `AccountWrapper` class, it have a list of `contacts` within.

Comment: @Mastor Could you modify my code,based upon accountwrapper reference.

Comment: @Sathya Sorry, you need to do it yourself, i don't have a lot time for that.

Comment: @Mastor Can you give me somelogic or some idea where should i have to modify my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12123/discussion-between-sathya-and-mast0r)

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question because questions about Apex should demonstrate a certain understanding of how to write Apex, and from the look of things, @Sathya can't understand basic references.

Answer (score 2):

Contacts are assigned to account using accountID field,just set this to assign any number of contacts to a account....

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a code sample.